# Enviar formulario automaticamente al cumplir Condición

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Como están colegas, pido de su apoyo ya que busco enviar mi formulario automáticamente una vez que mi input tenga 5 dígitos. tengo el siguiente código, sin embargo, no me funciona, espero y puedan apoyarme.

Formulario HTML

```html
<form id="attendance" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="hidden" id="HoraActual" name="hora">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="hidden" value="in" name="status" />
  <div class="fv-row mb-4">
    <input type="text" onkeyup="mayus(this);" maxlength="5" class="form-control form-control-solid" name="employee" id="codigo" placeholder="*****" required>
  </div>
</form>
```

Codigo Javascript

```js
$('#codigo').keyup(function() {
  var x = $(this).val();
  var codigoCompleto = x.substr(0, 5);

  if (x.length == 5) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'checar.php',
      data: codigoCompleto,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
          $('.alert').hide();
          $('.alert-danger').show();
          $('.message').html(response.message);
        } else {
          $('.alert').hide();
          $('.alert-success').show();
          $('.message').html(response.message);
          $('.nombre').html(response.nombre);
          $('#employee').val('');
          Swal.fire({
            position: 'top-center',
            icon: 'success',
            title: response.message,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 2000
          })
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

y aqui esta mi codigo PHP

```html
<?php
include 'conexion.php';


if (isset($_POST['employee'])) {
    $output = array('error' => false);

    $status = trim($_POST['status']);
    $employee = trim($_POST['employee']);
    $hora = trim($_POST['hora']);

    if (empty($employee)) {
        $output['error'] = true;
        $output['message'] = $conn->error;
    } else {
        $consultaNip = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT p.nip, p.id FROM personal p INNER JOIN ads_personal a ON p.id = a.idPersonal WHERE p.nip = '$employee' AND a.estatus = 1");
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($consultaNip);

        if ($row > 0) {
            $employee = $consultaNip->fetch_assoc();
            $id = $employee['id'];

            if ($status == 'in') {
                $consultaEntrada = mysqli_query($asistencias, "SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE employee_id = '$id' AND date = '$fecha_actual' AND hour IS NOT NULL");
                $rowE = mysqli_num_rows($consultaEntrada);

                if ($rowE > 0) {
                    $output['error'] = true;
                    $output['message'] = 'Has registrado tu entrada por hoy error';
                } else {
                    $registroEntrada = "INSERT INTO attendance (employee_id, status, hour, date) VALUES ('$id', '1', '$hora', '$fecha_actual')";

                    if ($asistencias->query($registroEntrada) === TRUE) {
                        $output['message'] = 'Acceso Correcto';
                        $output['nombre'] = 'Acceso Correcto';
                    } else {
                        $output['error'] = true;
                        $output['message'] = $conn->error;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            $output['error'] = true;
            $output['message'] = 'No se encuentra ningun empleado con ese NIP';

        }
    }
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Espero y puedan apoyarme en saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, ya que no encuentro como......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Tu código está llamando a `onkeyup="mayus(this);"` y la función `mayus` no la has incluido. Si esta función es importante debes incluirla, caso contrario quita ese atributo para que tu ejemplo sea reproducible

Comment: Hola @Yussef, Ya quite el **onkeyup="mayus(this);"**, sin embargo no jala

Comment: Agrega el código de `checar.php`

Comment: Debes depurar... Usa `print_r($_POST): die;` en **checar.php** para verificar que te esté llegando `codigoCompleto` . Luego puedes hacer `console.log(response);` y nos cuentas que datos obtienes en el inspector de código de tu navegador.

Comment: Listo @Yussef ya esta agregado.

Comment: Tienes que cambiar esta linea data: { employee: codigoCompleto },

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 problemas:

1.- No envías todos los datos de le formulario al hacer el POST, solo envías el valor de el input. Puedes usar `serialize` para envía el formulario

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'checar.php',
    data: $("#attendance").serialize(), //<---ESTO !!!!  
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) { //etc...
```

2.- Luego tienes un problema en tu validación en el lado de PHP, basicamente tienes esto:

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';

if (isset($_POST['employee'])) {
   $output = array('error' => false);
   //varias lineas
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Entonces si `isset($_POST['employee']` es `false` tu retornas `$output` sin haberlo creado anteriormente, porque lo creas dentro del `if`. Debes moverlo fuera

```
$output = array('error' => false);
if (isset($_POST['employee'])) {
   
   //varias lineas
}
```

Por otro lado, tienes una sobre anidación excesiva de `if`, te recomiendo busques algunos tutoriales para que veas como eliminar esas anidaciones que dificultan la depuración